# Combining normal Django Views with Django Rest Framework View

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I have a django application which is using Django Rest Framework.

I am trying to create user **password reset** flow using **Django Class Based Form View**.
For that I have defined URL's like:

```
url(r'^reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
        views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/$', views.ResetPasswordRequestView.as_view(), name='reset')
```

But the problem is that when I try visit the reset url, it shows the following error.

```
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<type 'NoneType'>`
```

I am unsure of whether mixing DRF views and Django Views is allowed.

What am I doing wrong? 
What should be the best approach to create a password reset flow using only DRF.

Edit , code of ResetPasswordRequestView

```
class ResetPasswordRequestView(FormView):

    template_name = "users/password_reset_template.html"
    form_class = PasswordResetRequestForm
    success_url = "#"

    @staticmethod
    def validate_email_address(email):
        try:
            validate_email(email)
            return True
        except ValidationError:
            return False

            # default method to handle post requests

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']

        if self.validate_email_address(email) is True:
            try:
                user_profile = Profile.objects.get(email=email)
            except Profile.DoesNotExist:
                user_profile = None
            if user_profile:
                # send mail here

                subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
                email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html'

                subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, message)

                # subject should not contain newlines
                subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
                email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, message)
                send_mail(subject, email, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [user_profile.email], fail_silently=False)
                result = self.form_valid(form)
                messages.success(request, 'Email has been sent to ' + email +
                                 "'s email address. Please check its inbox to "
                                 "continue resetting password.")
                return result
            result = self.form_invalid(form)
            messages.error(request, 'This username does not exist in the system.')
            return result
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid Input')
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Code for PasswordResetConfirmView

```
class PasswordResetConfirmView(FormView):
    template_name = 'users/change_password.html'
    success_url = "/"
    form_class = ChangePasswordForm

    def post(self, request, uidb64=None, token=None, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None
        try:
            uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)
            user_profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, Profile.DoesNotExist):
            user_profile = None

        if user_profile is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user_profile, token):
            if form.is_valid():
                new_password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                user_profile.set_password(new_password)
                user_profile.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Password has been reset.')
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Password reset has not been unsuccessful.')
                return self.form_invalid(form)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'The reset password link is no longer valid.')
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

The stacktrace shows the following, have changed the python path here(it is correct on my pc)

```
Traceback:
File "/[base path here]/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/[base path here]/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/[base path here]/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/[base path here]/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  468.         self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
File "/[base path here]/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in finalize_response
  396.             % type(response)

Exception Type: AssertionError at /user/reset/
Exception Value: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<type 'NoneType'>`
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from users import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', views.register),
    url(r'^check-username/$', views.check_username),
    url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password),
    url(r'^interests/$', views.get_all_interests),
    url(r'^signin/$', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token'),
    url(r'^verify-token/$', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.verify_jwt_token'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>[0-9]{1,6})/$', views.generate_feed),
    url(r'^community/(?P<community_id>[0-9]{1,6})/'
        r'(?P<user_id>[0-9]{1,6})/$', views.community_feed),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[A-Za-z_\.]{1,20})/$', views.user_profile),
    # url's for reset password
    url(r'^reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
        views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/$', views.ResetPasswordRequestView.as_view(), name='reset'),
]
```

Edit:
It works fine when I put the reset urls before other urls, but still don't know how and why?

Comment: The problem lies in the code for `views.ResetPasswordRequestView`. Can you post that class?

Comment: @joerick added code of the view

Comment: @ofnowhereland Mixin the two "paradigms" is totally allowed and valid!

Comment: Hmm, don't see anything wrong there. Perhaps in `views.PasswordResetConfirmView`?

Comment: @joerick Added that as well

Comment: Both views look ok to me. Is `FormView` a standard `django.views.generic.FormView`? Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: @ofnowhereland apologies, they both look fine to me.

Comment: @DanielHepper added stacktrace.

Comment: @ofnowhereland thanks. One more question, what are the base classes of FormView? `import inspect; print inspect.getmro(FomView)`

Comment: @DanielHepper I have the following import in my file
'from django.views.generic import FormView'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace, you will see that the error is raised in the Django Rest Framework code. That should not happen, because you a `django.views.generic.FormView` has nothing to do with DRF, so `rest_framework.views.dispatch` should never be called.

All the code you posted looks fine, the problem must be somewhere else. My guess is that something is wrong with `urls.py`, but this is really just a guess. As I first step, I would make sure that the right URL pattern matches.

Update:

The regular expression `r'^(?P<username>[A-Za-z_\.]{1,20})/$'` in the URL pattern for `views.user_profile` matches `'reset/'`. The URL resolver uses the first URL pattern that matches, therefor you have to put the URL pattern for `reset` further up in the list.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with urls.py .If the place the reset urls in the beginning it is working fine, but I still don't know why.

Comment: @ofnowhereland if my answer solved your problem, it would be great if you could accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I am still searching for the reason.

Comment: @ofnowhereland I didn't see that you posted the complete urls.py, please see my update